# Today is ELL's 100th day in beta! Time for a little self-reflection

Tags: discussion

Okay, to begin with: this is not an official requirement that we do any of this, or an official milestone of any sort.  But I thought that 100 days was a nice marker to stop and think back on the last three months, and bring up any thoughts or concerns we have about ELL so far. So, things I'd like us to think about:

- What are we doing well, that we should actively try to keep doing?
- What could we improve upon?
- Is there anything else you've noticed, good or bad, that you think we should discuss?

If you have something to bring up, please post it as an answer to this question.  We can discuss in comments to the answers.  We have a really great community, and I think we're building a good question base; but we can always improve, and we need to be reminded to keep up the good work as well!  So let's get talking.  What do you think we should be taking a look at, 100 days in?

Also, CONGRATULATIONS on day 100, everyone!

Comment: ... AND TWICE CONGRATULATIONS TO WHOM GAINED THE "FANATIC" BADGE!

Comment: @Carlo_R. Alas I missed a few days, and do not have that honor. I'm still upset that I missed private beta by two days!

Comment: I keep trying for the fanatic badge on multiple sites, but the stupid time zone difference keeps getting me.

Answer (score 5):

Well congratulations everyone on this beaming moment. I am glad the way ELL walked this far and  I am sure if we can keep this pace up, the door to become  a graduated site won't be too distant. Anyway I want to share some views which I have felt good about this site:

1) A fast growing community.

2) Hearty and respectful behavoiur of the fellow members.

3) Really serving it's purpose ie it's sticking to the business it is meant for.

But also it seems to me on some aspects, we can do more with this site. Like:

1) Given the aim of this site, it is expected that the visits/day should be more than it is now. I think we need to promote our site more. There is no need to bring the issue on how can we do that, we all know that more or less. What we need to do is to follow the steps regularly.

2) I am sorry to say, although 99% of our members are helpful, some, a few members are inclined to close or speak kind of roughly to OPs sometimes. I suggest we should be easy on them as this site aims on a language education. We know what are the customs that should be followed ideally before posting a question. If a new used does not know, make them know, but please don't drive them away. We need more users to bring this site a success.

Apart from these, this site is quite enjoyable and more popular than other sites of the same age; even senior sites sometimes fall short than this one :)

Anyway I wish all the best to this site.

**PS**- It would be very unkind of me, if I finish this before mentioning the moderators a big thanks. It would not be so easy, if you guys did not help the site all the way. Thank you for sailing the boat so beautifully. You are doing a great job.

Comment: I join with you in thanking our moderators Wendi and Matt, +1.

Comment: @Carlo_R  **And** waiwai933, who has been less visible but I am sure equally essential to the navigation.

Comment: RE: _I am sorry to say, although 99% of our members are helpful, some, a few members are inclined to close or speak kind of roughly to OPs sometimes_. I try to be a kind member, but sometimes questions ought to be closed nonetheless. A close vote isn't necessarily unkind, and even new members need to learn that questions should be asked with sufficient context. If nobody is ever brave enough to call a question substandard, then the site will get inundated with substandard questions. Also, questions that get closed can always be improved and reopened or asked again.

Comment: @J.R., generally speaking I agree, but, I think, we should define better or more precisely what "substandard"  means, especially considering the audience of this site, which is made, apart the experts, of learning people.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Please feel free to post an answer to this question discussing that in more detail. Personally I think *substandard* means the same thing here as it does on any other SE site; a poorly researched question, an overly vague or specific question, or an off-topic question. Just put effort into the question and usually it turns out fine :)

Comment: @J.R. It seems to me (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that Mistu4u was referring less to normal site procedures and more the the unnecessarily harsh tones and comments that once in a while are made.

Comment: @KenB: I've seen it go both ways. If you downvote and say nothing, that's considered unfriendly. If you explain how the post can be improved, that's considered unfriendly. And if you expound on your thoughts in meta, you get called a snob. I was merely pointing out that there are two sides to this coin: yes, some members probably could be a bit more polite and courteous at times; however, other times, very courteous members trying to make very polite remarks get misinterpreted as being hostile and unwelcoming, when really the O.P. needs to just be a little more open and a bit less defensive.

Comment: @J.R. Absolutely. Hurt feelings are sometimes inevitable when giving honest, useful, constructive criticism.